# liferay 6.1 & Tomcat 7 - change port

Tags: tomcat, dns, liferay, hosts, connector

After install Liferay 6.1 on Tomcat I want to execute my web app as `http:// myportal.local`.

I change file hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 myportal.local
```

I change file `server.xml`

from `<Connector port="8080"...` to `<Connector port="80"...`

But when I type URL `http:// localhost` or `http:// myportal.local` the response is a white page with

> It works!

May you help me please?

Comment: what is your expected output? and whats the role of life ray in this question?

Answer (score 0):

The port 80 is the port used by apache where all the http requests are served. By this line

```
127.0.0.1 myportal.local
```

you have given a name to your localhost so

```
http://localhost and http://myportal.local
```

will point to your apache port 80

Now you will be shown a white page with 'It works'. This is the index.html file present in your apache..

So what you have to do is, Keep your tomcat port as 8080 itself and  edit your workers.properties  and httpd.conf in your apache and redirect all the request to your tomcat.

Then you can either put your webapp inside the webapps/Root or edit your server.xml accordingly to reflect the url changes.

Don't forget to restart apache and tomcat after editing all these files.

Comment: I don't have apache installed, install apache is only way to goal?

Comment: do you have example? I'm installing Apache but i don't know what file change, and what change